# ping vpn client from openvpn server hosted on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, openvpn, route

I am very new to vpn and aws. I set up an openvpn instance from AWS marketplace and launch as default. I generated my client.ovpn files and successfully connected to my aws openvpn server.

From my client pc I can ping the aws openvpn server successfully by both server's internal (172.31.12.203) and external address. But I have trouble pinging from aws server to client pc by pinging client pc's local ip (192.168.13.100).

I already setup server-client bidrectional connection from openvpn client UI by following these guides ([one](https://openvpn.net/vpn-server-resources/reach-openvpn-clients-directly-from-a-private-network/), [two](https://openvpn.net/vpn-server-resources/troubleshooting-reaching-systems-over-the-vpn-tunnel/)). I still cant ping my client pc.

I also tried to add route from server to route traffic from server to client as the link suggests:

```
sudo ip route add 192.168.13.0/24 via 172.31.12.203
```

The client network structure is very simple:

- On client side, my client pc is behind a 4G router
- On server side, my aws openvpn instance is hosted in default vpc

I also used command on vpn server to debug while I am pinging from my client pc:

```
sudo tcpdump -eni any icmp
```

I got following output:

```
listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked), capture size 262144 bytes  
10:40:02.300012  In ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 100: 172.27.232.2 >     172.31.12.203: ICMP echo request, id 26256, seq 1, length 64  
10:40:02.300044 Out ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 100: 172.31.12.203 > 172.27.232.2: ICMP echo reply, id 26256, seq 1, length 64
```

My question would be how to ping from aws to my client pc?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a native [AWS Client VPN](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/clientvpn-admin/what-is.html) to access your VPC? The native solution will be cleaner to use.

As for diagnosing your OpenVPN setup, check that source/dest. check is disabled for the network interface on your OpenVPN EC2 instance.

Comment: Thank you Nathan, my purpose is to use access on-premise client network, I tried AWS Client VPN, it doesn't support access from vpc to client.